# Meteor, MUP & Cloudflare causing redirect/refresh loop

Tags: ssl, meteor, configuration, cloudflare, meteor-up

I have a meteor webapp that has been around for a few years. It hasn't been updated particularly often and thus the version is little bit old (Meteor 1.6.1.4), however it runs locally without an issue and I currently have a version of it it deployed without issue on a Digital Ocean droplet with Mongo on AtlasDB and the DNS on Cloudflare.

However I've been running into an issue deploying updates with the Meteor Up (MUP) tool. On my production server when I run `mup deploy` with my latest code the deployment works and validates successfully, however the live site now loops on page load. The page completes the load (including a call to Stripe API front end library) and the images load and as soon as that has happened the same page is loaded again over and over. This happens on each page of the webapp. There are no errors logged in the console.

I'm almost sure this isn't a codebase issue as I have a staging version of this same app running on an identical spec droplet which I can deploy to without issue. The only difference between the production and staging is that the staging uses a LetsEncrypt cert generated by MUP and production uses a Cloudflare issued cert. I can't remember exactly the reason for this as it was the outcome of my last round of troubleshooting, which did result in a successful deployment. The LetsEncrypt configuration with MUP seemed to be problematic when I last set everything up. Either way there is no obvious good reason why this error should occur.

So I think that the issue is most likely something to do with Cloudflare, however I don't have many clues as to what. I've tried clearing the full cache after deploying. I cannot disable the Cloudflare proxy as I get unsecure error.

For my next steps I'm thinking of setting up another staging droplet but with Cloudflare in front in the same way, to see if I can get a non-critical replicable version of the same error. From there I'm not sure what I would do to debug and fix. I was also wondering if configuring a load balancer for this webapp might be smart at this moment, though if in an SSL passthrough I wonder if it would not solve the underlying issue. This would also not necessarily be answering this question but rather just avoiding it. I'm also considering trying to update the version of the Meteor app as far as I can to see if there is any chance that codebase is part of the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you will better be served with the meteor forums for this issue, since it wont't be easily solved by an atomic answer imo.